# Generating logarithmic plots?

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot

[image]

Any recommendations on creating the diagram above ? Since the rest of the document was created in Latex (I am very sure) I am guessing this was made using tikz. But I have no idea how to

- generate the logarithmic axes
- label the **midband** range indicated above the plot

I am also confused about whether I should just eyeball the coordinates because it says below that it is just a **representative plot**. If you have made anything like this before, what is your approach ? Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: For start see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/477519/

Comment: Excellent comment by @Zarko, The same problem of a double logarithmic plot of gain and frequency. Searching the Tex group for logarithmic gives 275 results, look at (log1)[https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69032/single-double-logarithmic-axis?r=SearchResults&s=3|47.3199]. Try to use the "Search on Tex-LaTex..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to hazard a guess that this graphic is drawn in TikZ, but using gnuplot. I was able to do a decent job of reproducing the graphic--except for the actual data, that I have substituted with a simple plot of log(x).

Here's the result.
[image]

The gnuplot script looks like this:

```
# might add a hashbang for gnuplot here
set style line 1 lt rgbcolor "0x7799f0" lw 2 pt 6
set style line 2 lt rgbcolor "0xcccccc" lw 1 pt 6

unset border
set border 1 + 2 + 4 + 8

unset x2tics
unset y2tics
unset mx2tics
unset my2tics

set logscale xy 10
show logscale

set ytics format "$10^%T$"
set xtics format "$10^%T$"

set xlabel 'frequency (Hz)'
set ylabel 'gain'

set xrange[10:1E07] noextend
set yrange[1:100]
set xtics 10, 10, 1E07 logscale
set ytics 1, 10, 1E02 logscale

set mytics
set mxtics
show mxtics
show mytics

set grid ls 2

plot [10:1E07] log(x) ls 1

set terminal lua tikz latex color fontscale 1.0
set output 'experimental.tex'
refresh

set output
set terminal aqua
```

Note I'm using macOS here (thus the 'aqua' terminal). You'll have to read in the data instead of using the log(x) plot command as I did. You can see an example of reading in external data in [one of my github repositories](https://github.com/jessehamner/FourThirdsPaper/); look for `fourthirdsprofile.gpi`.

Once the output is written to `experimental.tex`, you'll need to compile the graphic by including it in another TeX document via `\input{}`. Here's a simple wrapper.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{graphicx,xcolor,lscape}
\usepackage{tikz, pgf}
\usepackage[left=0.5in,right=0.5in,top=1.0in,bottom=0.5in]{geometry}

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\SetUnicodeOption{mathletters}

\usepackage{gnuplot-lua-tikz}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{\gpbboxborder}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\input{experimental.tex}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}


% I added this "midband" label directly in the TikZ code, 
% which is easier than doing it via gnuplot:
\draw[<-](4,8.8) -- (5.25,8.8) node[xshift=1cm]{midband};
\draw[->](7.25,8.8) -- (8.75,8.8);
\draw[](4,9) -- (4,7.8);
\draw[](8.75,9) -- (8.75,7.8);

% drop these four lines into the gnuplot output near the 
% end of the tikzpicture and you should get an easily modified label.
```

Best wishes for the success of this paper.

EDIT: fixed an off-by-one error in my exponents; x axis range is now fixed.

Comment: this was very insightful. Thanks!. I don't have much experience with gnuplot. But I'll definitely try this out.